# Как Translate(), только для Scale. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется UI объект у которого надо плавно изменить Height. Через анимацию тут не подойдёт. Есть ли что нибудь похожее на `Translate()`, только для изменения размера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону твинов, там есть удобный функционал для подобных задач, избегая использования аниматоров и анимаций. От себя могу порекомендовать LeanTween, там бы это выглядело примерно так:

```
LeanTween.scale( myRectTransform, 
new Vector2(myRectTransform.rect.width, myRectTransform.rect.height * 1.5f), time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать сторонние плагины, как написали выше (сам пользуюсь DOTween), а можно использовать корутины - это сопрограммы, которые могут "засыпать" до нужного момента (например, до начала следующего кадра).

[В официальной документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Coroutines.html) их работу демонстрируют на примере постепенного исчезания картинки. Т.е. там каждый кадр в корутине постепенно увеличивается прозрачность картинки.

Думаю, с минимальными изменениями подойдёт для решения вашей задачи.

Для более полного понимания, можете ещё [вот эту статью на Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216185/) прочитать